# Que es el usurio User? Como soluciono esto? Donde puedo investigar?

Tags: permisos, users-roles, cuenta-usuario, directorioactivo

Gracias por interesarse.

Tengo un directorio en un servidor web windows 2008 R2 que tiene permisos para los usurios:
CREATOR OWNER, 
SYSTEM, 
Administrators, 
AD/myself_user, 
users.

Estoy usando un PC que esta connectado a un AD directory. Cuando comparto el directorio para usarlo en otro PC me borra los usuarios CREATOR OWNER y users quedando los permisos asi:
SYSTEM, 
Administrators, 
AD/myself_user.

Sin hacer nada, mas que compartir el directorio, mis programas no corren. (Esto me costo mucho descubrirlo. )

Uso Visual Studio para editar los programas que tengo en el servidor.  No los corro con visual, solo los edito y los corro con un browser despues de editarlos. Sin necesidad de tener el poolidentity con permisos en el directorio mis programas corrian correctamente antes de compartirlo.  Si autorizo alusuario users mis programas corren de nuevo.

Pienso que es riesgozo usar el usuario users. Donde puedo encontrar documentacion a cerca de este  grupo o usuario?

Mil gracias por compartir su conocimiento.

Comment: por qué está etiquetado con sql server?

Comment: Hey dipsiecamila, bienvenido!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a tu pregunta debes modificarla para que cumpla con la calidad requerida en el sitio, esto para que pueda ser bien recibida por la comunidad y obtengas buenas respuestas, para esto **es muy importante leer [ask]**, saludos!.  Evita preguntar varias cosas distintas a la vez.